# standardizing customer ids based on the same company name

Tags: r

I need to use one of the many customers ids and standarize it upon all companies names that are extact same.

Before

```
    Customer.Ids       Company        Location
    1211            Lightz           New York
    1325            Comput.Inc       Seattle 
    1756            Lightz          California
```

After

```
    Customer.Ids     Company        Location
    1211             Lightz            New York
    1325             Comput.Inc        Seattle 
    1211             Lightz           California
```

The customer ids for the two companies are now the same. Which code would be the best for this?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `match` here as it returns the first matching position. We can `match` `Company` with `Company`. According to `?match`

> match returns a vector of the positions of (first) matches of its first argument in its second.

```
df$Customer.Ids <- df$Customer.Ids[match(df$Company, df$Company)]
df

#  Customer.Ids    Company   Location
#1         1211     Lightz    NewYork
#2         1325 Comput.Inc    Seattle
#3         1211     Lightz California
```

where

```
match(df$Company, df$Company) #returns
#[1] 1 2 1
```

---

Some other options, using `sapply`

```
df$Customer.Ids <- df$Customer.Ids[sapply(df$Company, function(x)
                               which.max(x == df$Company))]
```

Here we loop over each `Company` and get the first instance of it's occurrence.

---

Or another option using `ave` which follows same logic as that of @Shree, to get first occurrence by group.

```
with(df, ave(Customer.Ids, Company, FUN = function(x) head(x, 1)))
#[1] 1211 1325 1211
```

Comment: It produces "Null"

Comment: @blueshift123 it works on your example dataset. Do you have some `Customer.Ids` as "Null" ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using `dplyr`package. It'll replace all Ids as per the first instance for any company -

```
df %>%
  group_by(Company) %>%
  mutate(
    Customer.Ids = Customer.Ids[1]
  ) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Customer.Ids Company    Location  
         <int> <fct>      <fct>     
1         1211 Lightz     New York  
2         1325 Comput.Inc Seattle
3         1211 Lightz     California
```